# How to get last N commands from history?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

I want to see what are the last N commands in my `history`. I thought `history | tail -n 5` would make it, but I noticed that a multiline command counts for as many lines as it has.

```
$ echo "hello
how are you"
$ history | tail -2
how are you"
1051  history | tail -2
```

So my question is: do I have to parse the output of the command to accomplish this?

Comment: // , This is why I love stackexchange

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I found it!

> **history [n]**
>
> An argument of n lists only the last n lines.

```
$ echo "hello
how are you"
$ history 2
1060  echo "hello
how are you"
1061  history 2
```

Comment: That seems to be for `tcsh`, `yash` and `bash`. You may want to give the corresponding information for other shells like `zsh`, `fish`, `ksh`, and the POSIX way.

Comment: I would love to, although I don't have any of these installed in my computer. Do you recommend any specific source to get the information from? In opengroup I see a reference to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: `fc -l -2` works too (but doesn't add current `fc -l -2` to output)

Comment: See also: [How to stop bash replacing commands in history with asterisks ? (‘*’)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36212/how-to-stop-bash-replacing-commands-in-history-with-asterisks).

Comment: `fc` by the way shows the last n commands with `-n`. Showing `from n commands until last` is only `n` (which does not make much sense because you need to know the total number). In german we would say `ein kleiner aber feiner unterschied`: A small but delight diff. Do not forget to use `-l` as @EvgenyVereshchagin pointed already because otherwise you end up in an editor which is not what you want.

Comment: `fc` can **hide line number** also. Eg: `fc -ln -1` will get the last command without line number

Answer (score 14):

You could also use negative numbers, like :

```
history -1
```

Or use a range (last 10):

```
history -1 -11
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with bash 5.0.11.

Comment: This is the way for zsh!

Comment: Does not work for me on Linux Mint `20.02` with GNU bash, Version `5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`: "invalid option." In German: `bash: history: -1: Ungültige Option.
history: Aufruf: history [-c] [-d Offset] [n] oder history -anrw [Dateiname] oder history -ps Argument [Argument...]`

Answer (score 6):

When you apply history it will show last history command as well. To prevent that space waster such alias could be handy:

```
alias hs=' history 16 | head -n 15'
```

(the command itself `history 16 | head -n 15`)

Another useful history alias:

```
  alias hsg=' history | grep '
```

(when ctr+R is too small to choose from)

The space in front of _history will run command not written in history

fc -l    # will also list 16 last commands  (and more)

Comment: While true, none of this addresses the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in OpenBSD 6.3 (PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2).

```
history [b]
```

Shows all the history beginning from an entry with a number [b]

```
history [b] [e]
```

Shows the history interval from [b] to [e]